# How to change/create a .svg file covered with font?

Tags: svg

I have a `.svg` file covered with font as below, I would like to change the font with my own words, do I need to create a new `.svg` file with relevant tools or just change the existed file? Thanks so much for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You need to recreate the SVG.